# How to get Facebook group created date using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As I can get other details of group like members, feeds etc, but being an admin, I want a created date of group using graph API. Please help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight option, but there are two workarounds to achieve something (it's not 100% perfect):

- you can get the date when the group was last updated: [Group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/), using `updated_time` field
- second option, you can create a doc, that the group was established, and when you will have created doc, you can access `created_time` field, on group docs: [Group-Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/groupdoc/)

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the only solution. but if there is no doc in group then you cannot get the created date too.

Thanks...